# How to remove password requirement from `dash` executable and add it to the dock

Tags: sudo, dock

I have 7 files for fan control which have following lines inside:

```
#!/bin/dash
echo level k | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

where `k` after `echo level` is from 1 to 7

The script runs fine, however it asks for sudo password every time. How to remove password from these files?
And is it possible to attach these files to the dock, so to activate them with a click?

The os is Ubuntu 20.04

*edit*
`ps auxc | grep -i therm` gives

```
root         153  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   May24   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root        6491  0.0  0.0 128404  1360 ?        Ssl  May24   0:02 thermald
```

*edit2*
`sensors` gives

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +51.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.54 V  

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        2997 RPM
temp1:        +51.0°C  
temp2:         +0.0°C  
temp3:         +0.0°C  
temp4:         +0.0°C  
temp5:         +0.0°C  
temp6:         +0.0°C  
temp7:         +0.0°C  
temp8:         +0.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +51.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
```

*edit3*
output for `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` :

```
G2ETA7WW (2.67 )
```

The laptop is `Lenovo Thinkpad x230` x64.

*edit4* `top` command:

[image: top command]

*edit5*

`sysctl vm.swappiness` gives  `vm.swappiness = 60`,

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` gives

```
cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` gives

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May  8 17:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May  8 17:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  8 17:31 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May  8 15:37 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 31 09:10 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

*edit6*

`snap list`:

```
    Name                             Version                     Rev   Tracking          Publisher            Notes
canonical-livepatch              9.5.5                       95    latest/stable     canonical✓           -
checkbox                         1.13                        838   latest/stable     ce-certification-qa  -
checkbox-snappy                  18.14                       2012  latest/stable     ce-certification-qa  -
chromium                         83.0.4103.61                1165  latest/stable     canonical✓           -
code                             5763d909                    33    latest/stable     vscode✓              classic
core                             16-2.44.3                   9066  latest/stable     canonical✓           core
core18                           20200427                    1754  latest/stable     canonical✓           base
gnome-3-26-1604                  3.26.0.20200529             100   latest/stable/…   canonical✓           -
gnome-3-28-1804                  3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498  116   latest/stable     canonical✓           -
gnome-3-34-1804                  0+git.3009fc7               33    latest/stable     canonical✓           -
gnome-system-monitor             3.36.0-12-g35f88a56d7       145   latest/stable/…   canonical✓           -
gtk-common-themes                0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable/…   canonical✓           -
htop                             2.2.0                       1207  latest/stable     maxiberta            -
kde-frameworks-5-core18          5.61.0                      32    latest/stable     kde✓                 -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18  5.68.0                      4     latest/stable     kde✓                 -
kolourpaint                      20.04.0                     56    latest/candidate  kde✓                 -
notepad-plus-plus                7.8.6                       232   latest/stable     mmtrt                -
odrive-unofficial                0.2.0                       2     latest/stable     ishan-bn14           -
pdftk                            2.02-4                      9     latest/stable     smoser               -
qalculate                        3.10.0                      248   latest/stable     h-k                  -
skype                            8.60.0.76                   128   latest/stable     skype✓               classic
snap-store                       3.36.0-80-g208fd61          454   latest/stable/…   canonical✓           -
submission-service               1.1                         12    latest/stable     codersquid           -
vlc                              3.0.10                      1620  latest/stable     videolan✓            -
whatsdesk                        0.2.18                      17    latest/stable     zerkc                -
wine-platform-3-stable           3.0.4                       6     latest/stable     mmtrt                -
wine-platform-5-stable           5.0.0                       4     latest/stable     mmtrt                -
wine-platform-i386               1.0                         25    latest/stable     mmtrt                -
wine-platform-runtime            v1.0                        136   latest/stable     mmtrt                -
zoom-client                      5.0.413237.0524             83    latest/stable     ogra                 -
```

`dpkg-query: no packages found matching *discord*`

and

[image: top command]

Comment: What is the actual problem that these scripts are supposed to solve? Do you have an overheating problem? Edit your question and show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`.

Comment: @heynnema the fan is too noisy at times. So I want to manually quiet it down for a while.

Comment: The fan is noisy for a reason. Your computer may be overheating. You have two thermal control programs running. Uninstall thermald with `sudo apt-get purge thermald`. Then install `lm-sensors` and edit your question with the output of the `sensors` command.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for informing about thermald. Edited OP.

Comment: Good. Now show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer. We'll check the BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema there you go.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Updated the bios, the fan is still noisy at times. May be some technical issue. Haven't figured how to add those shortcuts to the dock too.

Comment: Show me the `top` command when the fan is too noisy. Also see Update #1 in my answer. It's the *basics* for creating a .desktop file which can be launched from the SUPER key, and/or put into your dock.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema sorry, working these days. Will update on monday.

Comment: @heynnema added the screenshot of `top` when fan is noisy.

Comment: When looking at the `top` image, I see three things... you're out of RAM, and there's a Java app taking 104% of CPU, and gnome-shell is almost 20%. Do you know what the Java app is? Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema. I launched math calculator called Maple just to get fan speed up, but in quiet room without much CPU activity it is noisy as well.
Edited the OP.

Comment: Show me `snap list` and `dpkg -l *discord*` and a full-screen look at `top` again.

Comment: @heynnema in OP.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is... check your BIOS for a fan setting, have you installed any other thermal/fan control apps like TLP or fancontrol, find out what app/IDE was using java at 104% CPU, and add more RAM. Did my .desktop files idea work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **real** problem is: *The fan is too noisy at times*.

**thermald**

`ps auxc | grep -i therm`

```
root         153  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   May24   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root        6491  0.0  0.0 128404  1360 ?        Ssl  May24   0:02 thermald
```

You have two thermal processes handling thermal events. Purge `thermald`...

```
sudo apt-get purge thermald
```

**sensors**

After installing `lm-sensors`, the output of the `sensors` command looks fine.

```
Package id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +51.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

**BIOS**

You have BIOS G2ETA7WW (2.67).

BIOS v2.77 is available [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x230/downloads/ds029187) in many different formats. Updating the BIOS may solve your noisy fan problem.

```
fan1:        2997 RPM
```

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Update #1:**

Modify your scripts to be .desktop files, and place them in ~/.local/share/applications. Then you could run them from the <kbd>Super</kbd> key like normal apps, and/or put them into the dock. Sudo will still be required.

Rough example... **Fan#7.desktop**...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Fan#7
Comment=Fan Control
Icon=/path_to/fan_icon
Exec=sh -c "echo level 7 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan"
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;System;Utility;
```

You also need to get Properties on the new .desktop file, and enable "Allow executing file as a program".

Comment: Is it possible to install BIOS via ubuntu? The link you provided gives downloads for Windows.

Comment: @flowian There's a download for a bootable .iso also.

Comment: Thank you. The desktop apps do not work. I created these files in `~/.local/share/applications ` folder, added the contents as per your suggestion and added .desktop as a file type. They are not displayed in the apps though. I launched the file by pressing the `Super` key and locating the location and clicking it. It does nothing.

Comment: My .desktop files are standalone, and do not require any portions of your scripts. Please try again, using only the contents in my example. You may need to change the Terminal= line. You also need to get Properties on the new .desktop file, and enable "Allow executing file as a program".

Comment: chmod +x did the trick.

Comment: @flowian Great news! Did you have to change the Terminal = line?

Comment: Terminal=true works, only asks for password each when launching. Terminal=false does not work.